# How can I handle time series forecasting analysis with multiple series

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-science

OK, I'll ask in more detail. I'm updating the question and will add an image as well. I have the sectors and job vacancies data for those sectors as in the picture. The first column is dates and it's an index. the other 18 columns are job vacancies data for sectors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFD00.png)

Now my question is,

When I chart calculations such as seasonality and moving average, there are 18 tables for each sector.

For example, the healthcare industry, or mining.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfBB4.png)

I have exactly 18 of these three tables. At the end of the data preprocessing stage, I will have almost hundreds of tables. I wanted to tell them table by table in the readme.md section when I upload them to my github profile. But this way it won't be possible. Do you think I'm going right? I think about it. Or am I making things difficult for myself?

Is there any other way to analyze them? Can't I merge? I am open to suggestions at this point... I am doing time series analysis for the first time.

Comment: I don't understand how the question about "sectors" relates to the sample data about "company 1" and so forth.  It would also help if you showed how you might process a single series.  After that, I think it depends what question you want to answer with the data.  If you want a single overall forecast then you could aggregate across sectors and then forecast or forecast each and then aggregate.  If you want to forecast each sector then, well, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Hello, for example, I have unemployment belonging to the electronics sector, and the other sector is construction. There are 17 such sectors and what I'm trying to do in general is this. The overall goal is to create a model which will take industry (I) and number of years (Y) as inputs and output a forecast trend between [-1, +1] for that industry I into the future Y years (1,2,3,5 years). Now how can I analyze them? Including exploratory data analysis. For example, if I take out the seasonality and trend graphs of each sector, I have 51 graphs 

Comment: Are you saying you measure unemployment for industry sectors?  If so I don't know what unemployment for an industry even means.  You talk about seasonality, but you show annual data.  Is that right?   Usually seasonality is about variation within the annual cycle.  In any event, it doesn't sound like a single well-formed question.  Anyway, there's nothing inherently wrong with having 51 graphs.  Maybe there's a smaller number of distinct patterns among them?  But you're more likely to get help here if you can pose a clear well-formed question--the more specific the better.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. may you check again?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to explore 18 industries but you don't want to upload so many tables and charts.  One option might be to choose a representative sample of charts instead of an exhaustive set.  For example, if industries A and B show similar trends there may be little value added in showing both of them in an overview.  Conceptually I think you want to document the analysis process, then apply it across 18 industries showing indicative results, and then maybe give an overall summary of what it reveals across the whole economy, picking and choosing visualisations that help.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thank you very much, I will do this by taking into consideration what you've said.